# Conformal to a scalar-flat complete asymptotically flat metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

I'm studying a proof in Lee's *Geometric Relativity* shown below. The first half of the proof was just fine (hard though) with me, but after seeing his argument for $0<u<1$, I was completely lost. I mean, just because $u$ cannot be identically equal to $1$ doesn't mean $0<u<1$ everywhere. Yeah, Lee did mention the maximum principle and the fact that $u\to 1$ at infinity on each asymptotically flat chart, but what would his point be really? How could $u$ not exceed $1$ at some point? I need some assistance, please. Thank you.

> [image: Blockquote]

**Edit 1.** The reason why I can't deny the possibility of $u\geq 1$ is that there exists, by definition, a bounded set $K$ that is the complement of the union of all ends. On this $K$, $u$ may assume any values if no further constraint is imposed. Even if we work on the AF coordinate neighborhood, $u$ may still assume values no less than $1$.

**Edit 2.** I'm sorry. It seems like I will have to first know why $L_g$ is an isomorphism if I want to deal with this very question that also involves the maximum principle. Now I'm trying to know why $w$ attains a non-negative maximum or a non-positive minimum.

**Edit 3.** For future reference, let me enclose the definition of an AF manifold:

> [image: Blockquote]

**Edit 4.** I just found that the author assumes all manifolds are connected throughout his book. Then, since the bounded set $K$ is closed, the Hopf-Rinow theorem tells us that $K$ is compact being a subset of a complete Riemannian manifold.

Comment: You really need to use the maximum principle: fix a point $x$, and consider the value $u(x)$. For any open neghbourhood $U$ of $x$, you know that $u(x)$ is smaller than the supremum of $u$ on $\partial U$. This supremum can be made to approach $1$ by taking $U$ larger and larger, so you should get $u(x)<1$.

Comment: I haven’t read the full passage but isn’t this just maximal principle since it approaches 1 near infinity? Then nowhere in the interior can u exceed (or equal if you have strong max) 1.

Comment: Thank you guys, but I really don't know why it has to do with the infinity on each end. If $u(x)\to 1$ as $|x|\to\infty$, will we have $u(p)=1$ at some (manifold) boundary point $p$?

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR**

Recall strong maximum principle from Evans. If $U$ is a connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u$ is a subsolution (with usual regularity assumptions) to an 2nd order elliptic operator $L$ on $U$, either $u$ is constant or no interior point in $U$ can reach $\text{max } u$. Theorem A.2 from Lee's appendix tells us essentially the same thing holds when replacing $U$ with an arbitrary Riemannian manifold.

Since $L_g$ is the scalar curvature PDE, it is a 2nd order elliptic PDE, so we may use maximum principle on $M$. Since $u|_{\partial M}\leq 1$, so by strong max, $u<1$ everywhere in the interior of $M$.

**Edit: Here is an attempt to go through the entire proof, since the bounty asks for it.**

Before starting this proof, let me recall the weak and strong maximum principles (paraphrased from Evans) for 2nd order elliptic operators $L$ over a connected, bounded domain $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Lee tells us strong max holds upon replacing $U$ with $M$ in A.2.

> Let $L$ be a 2nd order elliptic operator with smooth coefficients nonnegative $c$, namely $Lu:=\sum_{i,j} a^{ij}u_{ij}+b^iu_i+cu$, where $u_i,u_{ij}$ denotes taking one partial and two partials respectively. We take smooth coefficient functions $a^{ij},b^i, c$. Suppose $L_u=0$.
>
> **Weak:** For some $x_o\in \partial U$, we have $u(x_o)=\max_{\overline{U}} u$.
>
> **Strong:** Suppose for some interior point $x\in U^\circ$ we have $u(x)=\max_{\overline{U}} u$, then $u\equiv \max_{\overline{U}} u$.

Let $(M,g)$ be an AF manifold with nonnegative scalar curvature. We seek a conformally flat metric $\tilde{g}$ which amounts to finding a positive function $u$ such that
$$\tilde{g}=u^{\frac{4}{n-2}}g$$
and $u\to 1$ as $|x|\to \infty$. With this choice, this is equivalent to solving the elliptic 2nd order PDE
$$L_g u:=-\frac{4(n-1)}{n-2}\Delta_g u+ R_g u=0$$
such that $u\to 1$ as $|x|\to \infty$. Equivalently, making the change of variable $v=u-1$, this is equivalent to solving the elliptic 2nd order PDE
$$-\frac{4(n-1)}{n-2}\Delta_g v+ R_g v=-R_g$$
such that $v\to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$. The specific asymptotic behavior of $R_g$ tells us that we can think of $L_g$ as an operator between the Sobolev spaces
$$L_g:W^{2,p}_{-q}(M)\to L^p_{-q-2}(M)=W^{0,p}_{q-2}(M)$$
since we ''lose two derivatives", and I guess the asymptotic behavior is also affected somehow. Our goal now is to show that $L_g$ is an isomorphism after putting specific constraints on $p,q$. In this case, we find that $v:=L_g^{-1}(-R_g)$.

Because we've transformed our problem to be $L_g v= -R_g$, this means $-R_g\in L^p_{-q-2}(M)$ which puts a constraint on $q$. Since we are also asking that $v\to 0$ as $|x|\to\infty$, this puts another constraint on $q$. If we choose $p>\frac{n}{2}$, weighted Sobolev embedding tells us $W^{2,p}_{q}\subset C^0_{-q}$. We need to put one more constraint on $q$ to ensure $L_g$ is surjective. To summarize the constraints:

1. $q<\text{ decay rate of g}$ since $-R_g\in L^p_{-q-2}$.
2. $q>0$ to ensure $v\to 0$ as $|x|\to\infty$.
3. $p>\frac{n}{2}$ for weighted Sobolev embedding (I know Lee mentions he needs a constraint on $q$ also, but the statement of $A.25$ does not seem to need any constraints on the asymptotic decay).
4. $q<n-2$ for surjectivity of the Laplacian.

With these constraints in place, we've successfully imitated the finite dimensional case where surjectivity is equivalent to injectivity. Therefore, suppose $L_gw=0$ and we aim to show $w\equiv 0$. By the above constraints, $w\to 0$ at infinity, and $R_g\geq 0$ and elliptic regularity of $L_g$ implies $w$ is smooth enough to satisfy a version of the strong maximum principle, which tells us $w\equiv 0$ everywhere. Thus, $L_g$ is an isomorphism, and such a $v$ exists.

Since $u=1+v$, it is smooth since $v$ is, so it also satisfies a strong maximum principle. Since $u\to 1$ as $|x|\to\infty$ and $R_g$ is nontrivial, $u$ is nonconstant and by strong maximum, $u<1$ everywhere on $M=\overline{M}-\partial M$. Since we asked that $u$ is positive, this tells us $0<u<1$, so indeed it is a conformal factor.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I really do. But I have no idea why $u|_{\partial M}$ cannot take values larger than $1$. That's the point.

Comment: @Wombat sorry, I am confused by your comment. We are *imposing* that $u\to 1$ at infinity, it is our boundary condition. Are you asking why it is possible to solve the equation with this boundary condition?

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon I have to admit that $u(x)\to 1$ is beyond my imagination. Please see **Edit 3**. Based on what I've learned so far, to say $u(x)\to 1$ as $x\to\infty$ on one end $M_k$ is another way of saying that $u\circ\Phi_k^{-1}(x)\to 1$ as the norm $|x|$ tends to infinity. This doesn't explain why $u$ cannot exceed $1$. For instance, a function $u$ without this property can still tend to $1$ if it approaches $1$ for only *large* $|x|$.

Comment: I feel like there may be a few things causing you confusion. First, as Johnny stated, we seek solutions u which go to 0 on the boundary. These are contained in sentences 2 and 3 in Lee’s proof. That is a requirement we impose. Given that we can find a solution under these constraints (and we can as it comes down to putting proper constraints on $q, p$ so that $L_g$ is an isomorphism), strong max tells us that the interior values of u is strictly smaller than 1.

Comment: @ZackFox Thank you, but I think we should go with $v:=L_g^{-1}(-R_g)$ instead of the one missing the minus sign. And I still don't know what tells us $w\equiv 0$, for which sure you would refer to the maximum principle and $w\to 0$ at infinity, but how? How do they interact with each other? That's the only tricky part for me, and that's why I fail to understand the similar argument for the fact that $0<u<1$ everywhere.

Comment: Since $w$ is a solution to $L_g$, i.e. $L_g w=0$, we may apply maximum principle to it. You can think of the statement of strong max as alternatively saying if $u(x)\leq C$ for every $x\in \partial M$, then $u(x)<C$ for every $x\in M$. Since $w(x)\to 0$ (similarly $u(x)\to 1$) as we go to the ends, i.e. $\partial M$, we have $w(x)\equiv 0$ (similarly $u(x)\equiv 1$) for every $x\in M$.

Comment: @ZackFox You just touched the key point: why do the ends belong to $\partial M$? By the definition of an AF manifold, these ends only share the complement of an arbitrary bounded set $K$ in $M$. What if some of these ends fall in $M\setminus\partial M$? Thank you.

Comment: Ok I see, I'm misusing terminology. When I said ends, I really only meant the $\partial M$, not what you posted in Edit 3. So, for example, an open cylinder has 2 ends in Lee's sense (where each end is diffeomorphic to a cylinder), whereas when I said ends of a cylinder, I was thinking of $S^1\sqcup S^1$. Let me edit my post to make this clear.

Comment: Anyways, is it clear to you that $\partial M\subset \sqcup M_i$, where $\{M_i\}$ denote the set of ends in Lee's sense? So eventually as $|x|\to \infty$ we'll eventually lie in one of the AF charts on some end $M_i$.

Comment: @ZackFox I'm sorry. It's not all that clear to me. Is it really possible to show that $\forall p\in\partial M$, $\exists k\in\{1,2,\ldots,\ell\}$ s.t. $p\in M_k$? Since $p\in\partial M$, there definitely exists a boundary chart $(U,\varphi)$ s.t. $p\in U$ and $\varphi(p)\in\partial\mathbb{H}^n$. Here $\mathbb{H}^n$ denotes the closed $n$-dimensional upper half-space. Then what's the next step? Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141344/discussion-between-zack-fox-and-wombat).